# Facebook API: Set Post Privacy via Friendslist

Tags: post, facebook-graph-api, privacy

I've looked into the Facebook API for posting an update with privacy settings. It seems like you cannot set privacy by friendlist, but can set it by individual user IDs instead. Does anyone know if setting privacy by a friendlist is possible, and if so, how?

Resources:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  When calling the post graph api, you send over the privacy settings that are linked in your first link.  You send over the field "privacy", which contains an array or dictionary of values.  The only required one is "value", with the options of EVERYONE, ALL_FRIENDS, NETWORKS_FRIENDS, FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS, or CUSTOM.  The rest of the rules about when you need to fill in the other array values (friends, networks, allow and deny) are on that site.

If you want to specify a friend list for you the post, you would first need to query the list of friends the user has, which would require the read_friendlist extended permissions.

If you've tried this and it doesn't work, post your code to indicate what you have tried.

Comment: Maybe you could help me on that. Can´t get it done. Thx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187215/facebook-sdk-post-to-wall-only-visible-for-me-for-testing-purposes