# Facebook SDK: post to wall only visible for me for testing purposes?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad

when i test my code using the Facebook SDK for iOS, all my post to my wall are visible for all my friends.
For all my testing purposes, i want to be able to restrict the postings. 
Within the Facebook page/preferences/Applications, i´m able to set the visibility for "post within my own name". When i change that to "only me", posting new content to my wall don´t work anymore (-> "Request didFailWithError").

Furthermore this preference will be reseted back to the default, after each deploy of a new build to my iPad.

Therefore i want to ask you, if there´s the ability to set it directly within my iOS app?
Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

Can´t get it done. When i output my request, i get this NSLog:

```
> Request didLoad: {
>     actions =     (
>                 {
>             link = "https://www.facebook.com/1608527xxx/posts/3278287008xxx";
>             name = Comment;
>         },
>                 {
>             link = "https://www.facebook.com/1608527xxx/posts/3278287008xxx";
>             name = Like;
>         }
>     );
>     application =     {
>         id = 274053732670xxx;
>         name = "iPad App";
>     };
>     comments =     {
>         count = 0;
>     };
>     "created_time" = "2012-04-17T11:12:46+0000";
>     from =     {
>         id = 160x527xxx;
>         name = "MyName";
>     };
>     icon = "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/yzwe/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif";
>     id = "1xx08527xxx_3278287008xxx";
>     link = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fxxxxxxxx";
>     message = "test caption";
>     name = "iPad App Photos";
>     "object_id" = 32782867xxxxx;
>     picture = "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/xxxxxx70_s.jpg";
>     privacy =     {
>         description = Friends;
>         value = "ALL_FRIENDS";
>     };
>     type = photo;
>     "updated_time" = "2012-04-17T11:12:46+0000";

-(void) postPhoto:(UIButton*)button{

    UIImage *uploadImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage"];

    NSDictionary *dictPrivacy = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"CUSTOM",@"value", @"SELF", @"friends", nil];

    //SBJSON* jsonWriter = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    SBJSON* jsonWriter = [SBJSON new];
    NSString* privacyJSONStr =  [jsonWriter stringWithObject:dictPrivacy];
    NSLog(@"stringPrivacy: %@", privacyJSONStr);

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   uploadImage, @"source", 
                                   @"test caption", @"message", 
                                   privacyJSONStr, @"privacy",
                                   nil];

    [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:(id)self];
    }
```

Any help on that?
Thanks
(Permission state:)

> NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
>   @"read_stream", @"publish_stream", @"user_photos", nil];

Comment: Maybe you should just create a test-user on facebook?

Comment: Thanks. If there are no other possibilities, i would do so. Or does anybody know about such an already included feature?

Comment: I understand your reasons (at least I think so). But I just recognized that a test-user would give you much more possibilities to play around without disturbing your contacts...

Comment: Where you got that console log?

Comment: Sorry you can add privacy to 'post or feeds' but not to 'photo'.just now i found out that. see this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: I´ve just tested the privacy parameter with a "dialog:@"feed", and the post is also visible to all my friends :(

Comment: Why you have added "description = Friends;" in privacy.Description field only needs to specified the country,language or city as per documentation.

Comment: If your api is outdated,pls update it.New facebook-ios-sdk is out there on github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally just use a test user on facebook with no friends. works for me!

Comment: I just found out, that on developers.facebook.com i can manage the "roles" for my app. Therefore its really easy to create random test users... (I´m still learning...  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a privacy for each post you are doing from your iOS App. Refer this page with a keyword "privacy".

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an API for creating test users, Facebook supports up to 500 test users per app: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/